# Using Ajax to hide/show certain divs

Tags: asp.net, ajax, html

How can I show / hide certain divs according to the selected value in the dropdownlist:

(for example, if Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius is currently selected in the dropdown, only the conversion div is visible)

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<p>
Please choose required calculation from the following list:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="calculation" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Addition of three numbers</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Calculate the side of a right-angled triangle</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Find x using the Quadratic Equation</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
</p>

<div id="addition" runat="server">
    <p>
    Input variable a : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varA"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input variable c : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varB"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input variable b : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varC"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="additionSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  
            onclick="additionSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblAddition" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="conversion" runat="server">
    <p>
    Input Fahrenheit Temperature : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="temperatureF"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="converstionSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="converstionSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblConversion" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="triangle"  runat="server">
    <p>
    Input side a : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tsideA"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input side b : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tsideB"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="triangleSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="triangleSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblTriangle" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="quadratic" runat="server">
    <p>
    Input side a : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sideA"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input side c : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sideB"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input side b : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sideC"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="quadraticSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="quadraticSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblQuadratic" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what have you done?

Comment: Are you trying to do this using code-behind, or a front-end UI library such as jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery this would work:

```
(document).ready(function() {
    doIt();
    $('#yourDropdown').change(doIt); //This is triggered on the change of the dropdown list

    function doIt() {       
        switch ($("#yourDropdown").val()) {
            case "addition" :
                $("#addition").show();
                $('#otherDiv').hide();
                break;               
           case "ConvertFToC":
               and so on....
            }
    }); 
})


<select id="yourDropdown">
  <option value="addition">addition</option>
and so on...
</select>


<div id="addition" >
    <p>
    Input variable a : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varA"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input variable c : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varB"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    Input variable b : <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="varC"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="additionSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  
        onclick="additionSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblAddition" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I was doing this with Ajax I would create a handler file (ashx) that would take the form info and work with it. However, I'm not sure I see the need for ajax from your question, showing / hiding divs doesn't require backend interaction surely?

Comment: Can you please find this jsfiddle as I modified the above solution for my needs but it is still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/UsjuH/

Comment: You've no library turned on in that fiddle, turn on Jquery and it works.

Comment: It worked on JSFiddle now but still not working on my solution. jquery library:

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Why two references to two different versions of Jquery? Stick with one, preferably the newer one.

Comment: Remove the runat=server from the divs you want to show / hide, .net dynamically generates IDs so the jquery won't work. If you need the runat server then you can either apply a class and use it instead of the ID in the Jquery or you can use something like <%= addition.ClientID%> to reference the ID. THats' all I can do to help I'm afraid, if you think my answer helped you can you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks, that's what was causing the problem.